# Double parenthesis for where clause using "IN" at gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm using the where clause to update a value at my database using gorm

`db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Where("id IN (?)", ids).Updates(users)`

The ids is a slice of ids and the user is the struct

The problem is that I'm getting this error

`Error 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

The sql that gorm generates is this one. It looks like that it creates a double parenthesis that is giving this error. But I don't know how to fix this

```sql
UPDATE `users` SET `status`='CANCELED',`updated_at`='2023-12-12 20:39:40.904' WHERE id IN (('066a75df-ba11-49c8-9b39-b1cce029760e','5f95f93e-94a5-46d1-86eb-dde83437ea26'))
```

**EDIT 1**

I had the same effect removing the () from (?)

`db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Where("id IN ?", ids).Updates(users)`

```sql
UPDATE `users` SET `status`='CANCELED',`updated_at`='2023-12-12 21:18:46.537' WHERE id IN (('066a75df-ba11-49c8-9b39-b1cce029760e','5f95f93e-94a5-46d1-86eb-dde83437ea26'))
```

`Error 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5014 and https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Clauses

Using this clauses I could do something like this

```golang
query.Clauses(
            clause.Where{
                Exprs: []clause.Expression{
                    clause.Expr{
                        SQL:                "id IN ?",
                        Vars:               []interface{}{ids},
                        WithoutParentheses: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        )
```